# Enum defined inside a struct has type undefined

Tags: solidity

I am using solidity ^0.8 and have the following variables defined inside a contract

```
  enum State {
    ForSale,
    Sold,
    Shipped,
    Received
  }

  struct Item {
    string name;
    uint sku;
    uint price;
    State state;
    address payable seller;
    address payable buyer;
  }
```

However, during testing, if I try to see the type of Item.state, it shows the type is undefined. I was expecting it to be of type "State". Please tell me what I am doing wrong here.

Here is the console log of my Item. I used the following dummy javascript test to get the console log (My contract is called SupplyChain)

```
let SupplyChain = artifacts
                      .require("SupplyChain");

let allObjects = SupplyChain
                    .ast
                    .nodes
                    .find(n => n.nodeType === 'ContractDefinition' && n.name === 'SupplyChain');

let structObject = allObjects
                          .nodes
                          .find((n) => n.name === "Item")
                          .members
                          .map((t) => ({
                            name: t.name,
                            nodeType: t.nodeType,
                            stateVariable: t.stateVariable,
                            type: t.typeName.name,
                            mutability: t.typeName.stateMutability,
                          }));

console.log(structObject);



{
    name: 'name',
    nodeType: 'VariableDeclaration',
    stateVariable: false,
    type: 'string',
    mutability: undefined
  },
  {
    name: 'sku',
    nodeType: 'VariableDeclaration',
    stateVariable: false,
    type: 'uint',
    mutability: undefined
  },
  {
    name: 'price',
    nodeType: 'VariableDeclaration',
    stateVariable: false,
    type: 'uint',
    mutability: undefined
  },
  {
    name: 'state',
    nodeType: 'VariableDeclaration',
    stateVariable: false,
    type: undefined,
    mutability: undefined
  },
  {
    name: 'seller',
    nodeType: 'VariableDeclaration',
    stateVariable: false,
    type: 'address',
    mutability: 'payable'
  },
  {
    name: 'buyer',
    nodeType: 'VariableDeclaration',
    stateVariable: false,
    type: 'address',
    mutability: 'payable'
  }
```

Comment: What code are you for computing the types?

Comment: @Ismael I have added the dummy javascript test to the question. The one which I used to get the console.log

Comment: I don't know why they are mapped to undefined, but for encoding purposes they are treated like the smaller uint that can hold all the possible values, uint8, uint16, etc.

Comment: If I use the solidity ^0.5 compiler however, I see that the type is State which is what I had been expecting. But it's somehow not the same with ^0.8